# How to transfer data between two components in a same .ts file

Tags: angular, components

I am working with Angular 7 and stuck on an approach, However, I gotta ask first, I have two classes on a same .ts file like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-component',
   template: 'app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app-component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
   instruction:any;
   constructor() { }
}

@Component({
   selector: 'app-modal-component',
   template: 'app-modal.component.html'
})
export class AppModalComponent{
   constructor() { }
}
```

I want to transfer data from `AppComponent` to `AppModalComponent`. Are they having Parent-Child relation or sibling relation?

I had tried `Input()` & `Output()` methods. But they do not seem to be working. The final option would be to use `Setter` and `Getter` through service(which I want to avoid for now.). Kindly assist in the matter.

Comment: Kindly avoid having multiple classes in a single file. Parent/Child relationship is not determined by when are classes defined. but rather where are they embeded in the view. For example, if `<app-modal-component></app-modal-component>` present inside `app.component.html` then Modal comp is a direct child of App component

Comment: Is there any chance to share data?

Comment: I'll update it to the child component ASAP. Right now I have to resolve this as it is now.

Comment: use `Rxjs`  `subject` for the same

Comment: @LalitMohan If you would show the view, HTML files then the relationship between them would make sense to us

Comment: You can always use a data service to share data between both components. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: Provide some more code for understanding

Comment: Two sibling components can only share data through a common dependency (like a service or a state store). As others have noted, multiple classes in a single file is extremely bad practice and should be avoided like the plague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to transfer data through `parameters and services` to modal component, But having these types of components on a same page is not an appropriate way to implement Angular. So i break apart `AppModalComponent` as a saperate component and import it into the module of `AppComponent`

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-component',
   template: 'app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app-component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
   instruction:any;
   constructor() { }
}
```

app-modal.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-modal-component',
   template: 'app-modal.component.html'
})
export class AppModalComponent{
   constructor() { }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AppModalComponent } from '../path-to-import-app-modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    ...,
    AppModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [],
  exports:[],
  providers: []
})

export class AppModule { }
```

This was the easiest and required way to get data through components, it only gets easy from here.